# English site for Hebrew language questions

Tags: discussion, hebrew

I've read in your FAQ that a question on Hebrew language is considered off-topic. Can someone please recommend a site (in English) where I can ask such a question? Thank you in advance for your kind cooperation.

Answer (score 5):

While it will be some time before this helps, see also [the proposed Hebrew site on Area51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75348/hebrew-language).

Answer (score 3):

You could try [italki](http://www.italki.com/answers/Hebrew), [quora](http://www.quora.com/Hebrew-language) or [HebrewResources](http://www.hebrewresources.com/discus/messages/27/27.html?ThursdayJanuary820040523pm).

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to ask and get answers in English, you can try [English Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary%3aInformation_desk) or [English Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aReference_desk/Language).