# Choose standard off-topic closure reasons

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

As described more fully in [a very informative post on `meta.stackexchange.com`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184154), which I recommend you check out, we're going to *lose* these two closure reasons:

> **off topic**
>   Questions on Mi Yodeya are expected to relate to Judaism within the scope defined in the FAQ. Consider editing the question or leaving comments for improvement if you believe the question can be reworded to fit within the scope. Read more about closed questions here.
>
> **too localized**
>   This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet. For help making this question more broadly applicable, see the FAQ.

In their place, we'll have an "off-topic" closure reason with customization. That is, if a user [votes to close a question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/privileges/close-questions) as "off topic", he will need to choose among some standard explanations of why the question is off-topic, or write one himself.

As described in [a different `meta.stackexchange.com` post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185097), the three site moderators are supposed to determine the most common closure reasons used on Mi Yodeya and present them to you all so you can choose three. Those three will be the default, standard explanations of a vote to close; again, anyone voting to close can supply a handwritten one instead.

*Note that we may actually have four standard closure reasons rather than three. Stay tuned.*

So the moderators have convened and, because we are three Jews, we have come up with four closure explanations. These are listed below as answers. (*Update: After a discussion in comments and the chat room, there are now only three answers below.*) Your mission, should you choose to accept it, is:

1. Please improve those closure explanations' wording by editing the answers below.
2. Please upvote or downvote them depending on whether you think they should be standard, default explanations: if we have only three standard explanations, but four answers below, one will not make the cut. *Please vote based on the general reason, not the exact wording, which is subject to change.* Please upvote any you think we should have, even more than three; community support for four explanations may help us *have* four.
3. Feel free to propose your own answers. (Note, though, that the moderators have fasted for three nights and days, and consulted site data, before choosing these closure reasons.) Note that the site [will still have](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184154) closure reasons for questions that are too broad, unclear, or seeking opinions, so don't propose those.

---

This feature went live with the following default reasons (supplied by SE):

- Purim Torah questions are on-topic only once a year, and will be closed after Purim.  For details, see: [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/purim-torah-policy-allowed-but-regulated)
- Questions on the Hebrew language are off-topic here except as they relate to Jewish law and tradition.  See: [English site for Hebrew language questions](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/660/english-site-for-hebrew-language-questions)
- Comparative religion questions are off-topic here unless they specifically request the Jewish perspective on a given topic.  See: [comparative religion questions](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/828/comparative-religion-questions)
- Questions asking for a practical ruling (p'sak halacha) are off-topic.  For practical advice [consult your rabbi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146).  Try to broaden the question so it applies to a wider audience, such as by asking what sources are applicable to the question.  ([More information](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/314).)

Comment: It will display the default, @ShmuelBrin. This will be something like, "This question does not appear to be about Judaism, within the scope defined in the [help]." ...but it can be customized further if need-be.

Answer (score 10):

Questions asking for a practical ruling (p'sak halacha) are off-topic. For practical advice [consult your rabbi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146). Try to broaden the question so it applies to a wider audience, such as by asking what sources are applicable to the question. ([More information.](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1734))

**Status:** chosen.

Comment: We need a much better landing page for "More information." Same goes for the FAQ.

Comment: Re @IsaacMoses's comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734

Comment: This answer was adopted as one of the initial reasons from SE (thanks!).  If no edits post-date this comment then there's no work to be done on this one *other than updating the landing page* (unless the community votes it down, but I suspect that won't happen).

Answer (score 8):

Comparative religion questions, and questions about what others have written about Judaism, are [off-topic](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1473) on Mi Yodeya. This includes any question that requires of its answerers any knowledge of a religion besides Judaism.

**Status:** chosen.

Answer (score 7):

Questions about the Hebrew language or about history or news of the Jewish people, Jewish individuals, or the State of Israel, *except as related to Judaism*, are [off-topic](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1473). If this question does relate to Judaism, please edit it to indicate how.

**Status:** chosen.

Comment: Why aren't this and the one about Jewish individuals combined? Too long?

Comment: @IsaacMoses This is already a combination of languages, history and law. (Not an answer to your question, but a comment.)

Comment: I would recommend either a) putting all of these adjacent topics in one close reason, b) grouping history and current events with people instead of with languages and law, or c) only retaining the most commonly-found of these - Jewish/Israeli history/news and Hebrew language.

Comment: Possible implementation of a+c: `Questions about the Hebrew language or about history or news relating to the Jewish people, Jewish individuals, or the State of Israel, *except as related to Jewish life and learning*, are off-topic.`

Comment: Also, how about replacing all instances in these of "Jewish life and learning" with "Judaism"? After years of seeing the former phrase around, I have trouble seeing what it adds that the one word lacks.

Comment: The last time I suggested switching to "Judaism": http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1498/faq-says-history-is-off-topic-and-on-topic?rq=1#comment5274_1499

Comment: How is Jewish history off-topic?  We have lots of history questions that are not about modern day life.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman, see http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1499.

Comment: (continued in chat [here ff.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10040521#10040521))

Comment: I've edited this post in accordance with my comments, above. With this one as it is now, I don't see much use for having [this fourth option](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1731/2) in addition.

Comment: How about `Questions about Jewish languages, history or people except as related to Jewish life and learning are off topic.`?

Comment: @DoubleAA `Questions about Jewish languages, history, countries, or people, except as related to Judaism, are off-topic.`? ("Countries" to include Israel and because the plural is necessary to avoid repeating "Jewish".)

Comment: Perhaps Polities?

Comment: @DoubleAA and msh210, I like generalizing to "Jewish languages," since that will include Yiddish and Ladino, both of which ought to be included. I think that the State of Israel should be included explicitly, since really, it is the only significant member of its class. Otherwise, I think we're sacrificing clarity too much in favor of brevity. How about: `Unless they are about *Judaism*, questions about Jewish languages, history, or people, or about the State of Israel, are off-topic.`

Comment: @msh210 Countries doesn't include Vaad Arba Aratzot, shtettle leadership and other things which are off topic for the same reason Israel is.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, I like that wording (and +1 on your comment). Anyone else want to chime in? DoubleAA, I know, but we don't need everyone whose question is closed to have to run to the dictionary.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I think the point here is to choose the adjacent topics that are the subjects of off-topic questions most frequently. Also, all of the examples you listed are easily associated with "Jewish history."