# What Yodeyan slang terms are there?

Tags: discussion, chat, comments, community, glossary

What are slang terms that people on Mi Yodeya use in comments or chat that are unique to this community?

Please post one term with definition, etymology, earliest known usage, etc., per answer.

Please only include terms that can reasonably be considered to genuinely be part of the communal lingo. For example, one known usage of a term or your invention of what you think would be a neat term are not good enough.

The goal of this post is to create a searchable reference that people can discover if they encounter one of these terms in the wild and have no idea what it means.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5030562#5030562

Comment: related http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/581/759

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/236

Answer (score 15):

**TZT** / **Time zone tov** / **Good time zone** - Have a good one.

"TZT" is an initialization of "time zone tov."

"Time zone tov" is a partial Hebraization of "good time zone," adopting the form of the common Hebrew greeting ["Shavua' tov"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_greetings#Shabbat) ("Have a good week.")

"Good time zone" is meant to be an equivalent of "Good day" or "Good night," to be used when the speaker is either unsure, due to Internet anonymity, of which time-of-day-based greeting would be appropriate for those being addressed or is addressing people in multiple different time zones.

Earliest known use of "Good time zone" on Mi Yodeya: [msh210](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/5926/msh210) in [V'dibarta Bam](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/vdibarta-bam) on [June 16, 2011](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1155559#1155559).

Earliest known use of "Time zone tov": [Isaac Moses](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/3584/isaac-moses) in [V'dibarta Bam](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/vdibarta-bam) on [March 10, 2013](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8453890#8453890).

Earliest known use of "TZT": Explicit coinage by [HodofHod](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/23459/hodofhod) in [V'dibarta Bam](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/vdibarta-bam) on [March 10, 2013](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8453964#8453964).

Comment: That's incredibly useful. ;-)

Comment: @JonEricson, thanks! I hope you also enjoyed the chiastic structure of the writeup. :)

Comment: It's not just Shavua' Tov, but also Boker Tov, Layla Tov, Erev Tov and Tzohorayim Tovim.

Comment: @DoubleAA [And "_shabas tov_".](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/5450)

Answer (score 11):

**yodeyan** - A member of the [Mi Yodeya](http://mi.yodeya.com) community.

Generated by affixing the [suffix "-an"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/an_2) to the word "[Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9/what-does-mi-yodeya-mean)," from the community's name.

Earliest known usage: [Isaac Moses](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/2/isaac-moses), in a [January 18, 2010 post](http://yodeya.blogspot.com/2010/01/more-from-linkedin-what-if-crowd-is.html) on the ["lo.yodeya" blog](http://yodeya.blogspot.com/) that he wrote during the early days of [mi.yodeya](http://web.archive.org/web/20100424030814/https://judaism.stackexchange.com/) [1.0](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/where-did-all-these-posts-come-from) said, fruitlessly (except for the coinage):

> I'd be very interested to hear your thoughts, yodeyans, in the comments on this post.

Comment: Oh cool; when I used it in my election blurb I thought I was coining it.  So glad to hear there was earlier usage -- 2.5 years earlier, even!  (Variant: I usually capitalize it.)

Answer (score 9):

**Rfפ** - Request for פְּסַק (*pesak* / rabbinic ruling)

Presumably pronounced, if at all, "arr eff pay."

This is shorthand for a characteristic of a question that [could cause it to be closed](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1729/choose-standard-off-topic-closure-reasons/1733#1733) on Mi Yodeya - requesting a practical ruling, as if from a rabbi.

Earliest known usage: Scimonster, [in an edit summary](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/revisions/29768/10), November 24, 2014.

Earlier, inferior version, *RfP*, earliest usage: Isaac Moses, [in Bam](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18669887#18669887), November 18, 2014.

Answer (score 8):

**Bam** -- our main general site-related chatroom, [V'dibarta Bam](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/vdibarta-bam).

Earliest known comparison of the word בם to the English onomatopoeia [*BAM*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NPjV.gif): [msh210](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/5926/msh210) in Bam on [2012 May 23 15:41](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4698858#4698858)

Earliest known usage as a stand alone name: [Adam Mosheh](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1059/adam-mosheh) in Bam on [2012 Jun 13 14:24](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5350857#5350857)

Earliest known Hebrew usage: [Double AA](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/759/double-aa) in Bam on [2012 Jun 15 22:50](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4979494#4979494)

Answer (score 5):

**JeLLy** - of or related to **J**ewish **L**ife and **L**earning

It derives from when the site was defined as not Judaism, but Jewish Life & Learning.  Basically, if something is JeLLy, then it is on-topic for this site, and if it's not, then it is not.

Earliest known usage: [Feb 6, 2013 by @msh210](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/468?m=7986595#7986595) in Bam:

> Isaac Moses: @msh210 Can you [edit] in a JL&L-relevant motivation?
>
> msh210: @IsaacMoses Can't think of one that I'm sure y'all'd consider JeLLy.

Comment: What is the latest known usage?

Comment: @Daniel all known uses: http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=jelly&room=468.  (I searched in posts using [my data query](http://data.stackexchange.com/jewish%20life%20and%20learning/query/115197/uses-of-any-given-word-by-user), but found nothing)

Answer (score 5):

**PTIJ** / **p-t-i-j** - Purim Torah - in jest

This term is the initialization of the [purim-torah-in-jest](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/purim-torah-in-jest) tag, which is applied, in accordance with the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/purim-torah-policy-allowed-but-regulated), to in-season non-serious questions.

Earliest known usage: May 8, 2013 by Isaac Moses, [in Bam](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/468?m=9337397#9337397):

> @msh210 File away for PTIJ 5774: this pun, along with conspiracy theories

Answer (score 5):

**O-Cmon** (also **O-כמאן**) - A fictitious kosher-certification agency with notoriously low standards.

This *hechsher* was [first mentioned](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14951/1713) on a [PTIJ](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3472/1713) question from 2012 asking what a particular strange marking was on some foods. The answer describes it as "the world’s first crowd-sourced Kosher certification."

This agency is occasionally mentioned on Mi Yodeya (e.g. [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/55529/1713), [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26575/claims-on-food-labels-says-who#comment60550_26575), and [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/69098/what-kind-of-horns-did-moshe-have#comment197976_69098)) almost always in a joking way.

Comment: It's [_burp_] fictitious?!??!?! _goes to induce vomiting and throw away the rest of his bacon sodas_

Answer (score 4):

[image: Bronze shabbat badge awarded to Shalom, represented as "shabbat Shalom"]

This image is an excerpt from a screenshot of the Badges sidebar on the front page of the Judaism Stack Exchange beta website<sup>1</sup>, indicating that [user Shalom was awarded](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/badges/77/shabbat?userid=21) the bronze badge for answering questions in the [shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shabbat) tag. Because it shows the words "**shabbat Shalom**," it's used in Chat as a humorous way for people to wish each other [*Shabbat Shalom*](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5445/where-did-shabat-shalom-come-from).

Earliest usage (and image credit): June 16, 2011 by msh210, [in Bam](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/468?m=1158336#1158336).

---

<sup>1. Which is why it looks different from the current [Mi Yodeya Badges page](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/badges). (Hat-tip: DoubleAA)</sup>