# Meya Alafim - Mi Yodeya? Gershon Gold Yodeya!

Tags: discussion, celebration

### Who knows one hundred thousand?

### [Gershon Gold](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/200/gershon-gold) knows one hundred thousand!

[image: 100,000]

[*Yeyasher Kochacha*](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/61480/what-is-the-source-and-reason-for-saying-yeyasher-kochacha-or-chazak-ubaruch) to [Gershon Gold](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/200/gershon-gold) for achieving 100,000 reputation points! [*Mazal Tov*](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/790/why-do-we-say-mazel-tov-shouldnt-we-thank-hashem) for being the first [Yodeyan](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1763/) to make it there!

Think about what this means: Something like ten thousand times, another member of the community saw a question or answer Gershon Gold wrote and thought "yes, that's valuable." Who Knows how many other times people have read and benefited from his contributions?

[image: Gershon Gold flair]

Over the years, Gershon Gold has demonstrated great research skills, often coming up with on-point sources for interesting Halachic questions very quickly. He has also been an exemplar of [*tzeniut*](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/592/), concentrating on writing great questions and answers and keeping his personal life to himself.

If you would like to join in this celebration of Gershon Gold's many contributions to Mi Yodeya, feel free to post congratulations or a link to a favorite one of his posts in an answer here.

May you go from strength to strength, Gershon Gold!

Comment: Plus Gershon has the more total badges than any other user.

Comment: @DoubleAA It would be nice to document that in an answer post. :)

Comment: awesome. [15 char]

Comment: Asarah Ribo? [char]

Comment: Mi Yodeya if Gershon stays up at night thinking of questions and answers? May I ask which you like better and why?

Comment: @DonielF Six of one, a half-dozen of the other :)

Comment: Related: ["Is it bad for one to let bits of one's personal life become known online?"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/81786/is-it-bad-for-one-to-let-bits-of-ones-personal-life-become-known-online)

Answer (score 4):

Congratulations, dear Gershon.  Yeyasher kochacha!