# Meya Alafim - Mi Yodeya? Shalom Yodeya!

Tags: discussion, celebration

### Who knows one hundred thousand?

### [Shalom](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/21/shalom) knows one hundred thousand!

[image: 100,000]

[*Yeyasher Kochacha*](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/61480/what-is-the-source-and-reason-for-saying-yeyasher-kochacha-or-chazak-ubaruch) to [Shalom](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/21/shalom) for achieving 100,000 reputation points! [*Mazal Tov*](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/790/why-do-we-say-mazel-tov-shouldnt-we-thank-hashem) for being the second [Yodeyan](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1763/) to make it there!

Think about what this means: Something like ten thousand times, another member of the community saw a question or answer Shalom wrote and thought "yes, that's valuable." Who Knows how many other times people have read and benefited from his contributions?

[image: Shalom flair]

Shalom has been with Mi Yodeya since the very beginning, eight years ago. His great contributions early on earned him moderator standing in the [mi.yodeya 1.0](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/where-did-all-these-posts-come-from) days. Since then, he has posted nearly 2000 questions and answers on all kinds of topics, and distinguished himself especially with his carefully-written, compelling explanations of sensitive topics.

[Here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/89424/2), if I'm not mistaken, is the answer that put him over the edge. Fittingly, it involves eating bugs, much like [this very early answer of his](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/213/why-would-a-product-be-only-for-cooking-and-pureeing/214#214), which was later featured in a [major motion picture](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2AAOoGWZZ7A).

If you would like to join in this celebration of Shalom's many contributions to Mi Yodeya, feel free to post congratulations or a link to a favorite one of his posts in an answer here.

May you go from strength to strength, Shalom!